# Sql : Based on column value do sum/substract

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having data in sqltable like below :

```
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
| Id | PayId | DeductionId | Amount |
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |     1 |           0 |    100 |
|  2 |     2 |           0 |    250 |
|  1 |     0 |           3 |     50 |
|  2 |     0 |           4 |     75 |
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
```

So in output, need group by on Id and when PayId is non-zero then do sum of amount and when DedctionId is non-zero then do sum of amount and substract of those two values. So need Output like below :

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Amount |
+----+--------+
|  1 |    50  |
|  2 |    175 |
+----+--------+
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, both are never non-zero.  You just want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when payid > 0 then amount
                when deductionid > 0 then - amount
                else 0
           end) as amount
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement for the SUM:

```
select 
  Id,
  sum(
    case when payid <> 0 then amount else 0 end - 
    case when deductionid <> 0 then amount else 0 end
  ) Amount
from tablename
group by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25bc42dfe10f7ffda201e17a30e09b35).
Results:

```
> Id | Amount
> -: | -----:
>  1 |     50
>  2 |    175
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple case expression should work here for you.

```
select Id
    , Amount = sum(case when PayID > 0 then Amount else Amount * -1 end)
from YourTable
group by Id
```